# Create collection of stubs with mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I want to create Collection of stubs so that first Item when I call getId() method return 0, second Item.getId() return 1 and so on. Value of getId() method must be equal index of element. I try this

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private List<Item> items;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void mockCollection() throws Exception {
    when(items.get(0).getId()).thenReturn(0);
    when(items.get(1).getId()).thenReturn(1);
    ...
}
```

But I get this Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$42aa7d0b cannot be cast to com.gubin.designpatterns.behavioural.observer.Item
```

How I can do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to mock `Item` as well.

```
@Mock
private Item item1;
@Mock
private Item item2;

@Test
public void mockCollection() throws Exception {
    when(items.get(0)).thenReturn(item1);
    when(items.get(1)).thenReturn(item2);
    when(item1.getId()).thenReturn(1);
    when(item2.getId()).thenReturn(2);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why doesn't RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS  work in this situation? I think it must mock get(int) method and then mock getId() method or I don't understand RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS correctly.

Comment: What `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` may do is to return the same object no matter which parameter you send. So, you need a way to specify that you want different objects to be returned depending on the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for refinements

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private List<Item> items;
```

Simply: wrong. You **never** mock a class that is so easy to create with real code.

You simple create an ordinary ArrayList (or any other thing that implements List) and fill that with mocked answer objects; configured to return the expected values.

Thing is: you use *mocking* as seldom as possible. It is a nice and convenient helper, but when you can go without it (and as said; that is super easy here); you simply don't do it.